# wkwebview window.webkit.handler.postMessage reload the current page

Tags: javascript, ios

When I call a javascript function like this inside a WKWebView to post a message to iOS swift:

```js
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    window.webkit.handler.postMessage('Message from web pages.');
 });
```

the current web page is always been reloaded. Is there a way to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

The correct JavaScript call is:

```
window.webkit.messageHandlers.<your-handler>.postMessage('Message from web pages.');
```

You need to replace `<your-handler>` with the namespace of the handler you defined in your `WKWebView`, e.g

```
[_webView.configuration.controller addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"Ti"];
```